# MATLAB constrained optimization with theta constraints

Tags: matlab, optimization, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I want to find the theta that minimizes l2 norm of y-X*theta, and constraint is that some element of theta should equal to 0. How do I do this in MATLAB?

My y is 10x1, X is 10x9, theta is 9x1

I think using gradient descent may be helpful not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple interpretations possible here, because of the informal description.

If you just want to solve the linear least-squares problem and a-priori fix some variables to zero, use matlab's [lsqlin](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) and use `upper-bound=lower-bound=0` for those variables.

If somehow your task is to solve the same objective subject to something like: `at least w values of theta are 0`, this is probably NP-hard (in the general setting) and you would need Mixed-integer Quadratic-Programming or Mixed-integer Second-order-cone Programming. In this case, i'm not sure if there is a solver available. Some open-source solvers would be Bonmin (Couenne, to a lesser degree) or most commercial solvers like (Gurobi, CPLEX, Mosek).

Comment: To add the the second interpretation, if we want to find a sparse theta in general this implies minimizing the L0-norm of theta. Instead if we relax the problem to minimize the L1-norm (which is convex) then the problems are equivalent under certain constraints. [Good read!](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/ExactRecovery.pdf)

Comment: Yes, l1-norm is sparsity-inducing. Yes, it can be solved by the same solver. But it's non-smooth and needs reformulation (e.g. by using constraints; the original problem here was bounded but unconstrained). It's also different then the at-least-w-val problem.

Comment: okay i solved my own problem, just used a subset of my X where the constraint would be satisfied. then just solve for theta using the subset